# "Use of unknown namespace" when adding custom namespace

Tags: xml, rss

I'm trying to use custom elements in an RSS feed (to render in XSLT), and I'm trying to namespace them to avoid validator errors. However, I'm getting "Use of unknown namespace".

My understanding is that I can use an arbitrary URL as the namespace URL. However, it seems like I can use only a specific set of namespaces that are built into RSS readers. Is there a way to define a custom namespace without triggering a validator error?

Also, would spec-compliant RSS readers be able to parse RSS feeds with this error?

Answer (score 1):

I get the same message from feedvalidator. I think it's just a warning, but regardless the validator is wrong to flag it. One of the great things about xml is that you can create your own namespaces. That the validator complains indicates the authors, who are human, failed to understand the purpose of namespaces. Ignore the warning.

Comment: regardless or not, I got the same issue, and because this,Podcasts Google refuses to publish a podcast till the moment this misalignment is solved. And it's realy annoying